# XIDEL export extracted data (div) from multiple HTML files into new HTML files

Tags: html, xidel

I would like to scrap a website of multi pages and extract a particular div before exporting it to html pages with just the div as content.

I am able to extract data from the content using Xidel with the following command

```
xidel http://someURl/ --extract //div[2]/div[2]/div -f "//a" -e //div[2]/div[2]/div
```

Is it possible to download the extracted data into a html file?

Answer (score 1):

add a parameter:   --output-format=html

Comment: More Information on how this fixes the problem, please.  Thank you

Comment: It actually does, because with --output-format=html the result will be `<!DOCTYPE html><div>[content-if-extraction]</div>`, just as the author is asking.